# Windows disabled hardware acceleration for Firefox

Tags: windows-11

I have Windows 11 and GeForce RTX 2060. I noticed recently that Facebook pages occasionally turned "blank" on my Firefox like something was wrong with them. If I wiggle my mouse, they will turn back to Facebook content.

Yesterday I visited some page that would cause exact same thing to Firefox, but this time the hopping between blank and normal went forever. In the end, I got a Windows notification that Firefox had been blocked from accessing graphics hardware. Fine, Facebook did not flicker anymore, but now all YouTube videos turn green!

I will update the video driver, but how do I turn back on hardware acceleration for Firefox in Windows? I am asking about a Windows system setting that I can't find.

Comment: You probably ran out of GPU RAM, which caused 'randomness' until reset. That's what triggered the OS to block the culprit. FB is a notorious RAM hog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that installing the [latest driver](https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx) also resets this setting. I did not change any setting, but no pages turn blank anymore, and YouTube videos are also fixed.

Comment: To make this answer useful to others, provide the ID's of the drivers and the location where you found them.

Comment: I don't know what a driver ID is, but I added the location. Standard stuff. One should take what is appropriate for them starting from this page. I assumed I'd get this automatically from Windows Update, but there you have it.

Comment: By ID, I meant either the name, or update number, but including the URL helps, so +1.